# Set different option selected option on refresh of the page -- JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have a table as follows:

```
<select id="CellLayout" style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;" onChange="PipeConfigChange(this.value);">
    <option>select layout</option>
    <option>blinker</option>
    <option>glider</option>
    <option>flower</option>
    <option>custom</option>
</select>
```

on default, 'select layout' is what is displayed. on the click of a button, i need the select box to display 'custom'. i tried searching around SO, but I'm trying to do this without Jquery..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... Its simple... Really Works..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fun()
{

document.getElementById("CellLayout").selectedIndex = 4;
}
</script>


<form name="f1">
<select id="CellLayout" style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;" >
    <option>select layout</option>
    <option>blinker</option>
    <option>glider</option>
    <option>flower</option>
    <option>custom</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="fun()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The select element must have a name to be successful, the form can have just an ID though, in which case you could do `document.forms.f1.CellLayout.selectedIndex = 4`, and directly from the button you can do: `onclick="this.form.CellLayout.selectedIndex = 4;"`

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the selects value, like so :

```
<select id="CellLayout" style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;" onChange="PipeConfigChange(this.value);">
    <option>select layout</option>
    <option>blinker</option>
    <option>glider</option>
    <option>flower</option>
    <option>custom</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="change" onclick="change()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function change() {
    document.getElementById('CellLayout').value = 'custom';
}
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fAt4Z/)

Comment: Good, but doesn't work in IE 7 and lower. Those versions don't correctly implement option text and value behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
<select id="CellLayout" style="color:#000; font-family:monospace;" onChange="PipeConfigChange(this.value);">
    <option value="0">select layout</option>
    <option value="1">blinker</option>
    <option value="2">glider</option>
    <option value="3">flower</option>
    <option value="4">custom</option>
</select>
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="setSelected">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.onclick = function(){
        var layOut = document.getElementById('CellLayout');
        for(var i = 0; i < layOut.length; i++){
            if(layOut.options[i].value == '4'){
                layOut.selectedIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understand of your question. May be following is your answer. Please check.

In html:

```
<select id="CellLayout" style="color:#99FF00; font-family:monospace;" onChange="PipeConfigChange(this.value);">
    <option>select layout</option>
    <option>blinker</option>
    <option>glider</option>
    <option>flower</option>
    <option>custom</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="clickHere" onclick="javascript:call()"/>
```

In javascript:

```
function call() {
        var textToFind = 'custom';
        var dd = document.getElementById('CellLayout');
        for (var i = 0; i < dd.options.length; i++) {
            if (dd.options[i].text === textToFind) {
                dd.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```